# How to query list from custom created web part

Tags: 2010, web-part, database, query, c-sharp

I have built a custom visual web part in c# for SharePoint 2010. What I would like to do is be able to query a specific list in SharePoint and then process the results. I am a complete noob when it comes to SharePoint (but do have extensive experience developing Drupal solutions). I can create a query string no problem:

```
SELECT 'GenericName' FROM 'MyTable' WHERE 'GenericName' LIKE 'something%'
```

My question is how do I set up my web part to process the query? I assume there must be some boilerplate code that accomplishes this as this must be a fairly common operation. I have seen the following code:

```
SearchServiceApplicationProxy proxy = (SearchServiceApplicationProxy)SearchServiceApplicationProxy.GetProxy
   (SPServiceContext.GetContext(SPContext.Current.Site));
        KeywordQuery query = new KeywordQuery(proxy);
        query.ResultsProvider = Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchProvider.Default;
        query.QueryText = queryText;
        query.ResultTypes |= ResultType.RelevantResults;
        ResultTableCollection searchResults = query.Execute();
```

However, I think this code is for accessing SharePoint's default search page and not targeting a specific list (but maybe I am wrong about that).

Can anyone tell me what I need to do with some code examples?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In SharePoint querying of lists is done using [CAML query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms467521(v=office.14).aspx) instead of SQL queries. Tools like [CAML Query Helper](https://spcamlqueryhelper.codeplex.com) and [U2U CAML Query builder](http://www.u2u.be/Downloads/U2U.SharePoint.CQB2010.zip) can be used to generate your query and to test it.
2. Check this post on [creating Visual Webparts for SharePoint 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff597539(v=office.14).aspx)
3. Now you can use below code as a starting point for reading data from list.

> ```
> using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.URL)) {
> using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
> {
>     // choose the list
>     SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("insert your list Name");
>     if(list!=null)
>     {
>         SPQuery myquery = new SPQuery();
>         myquery.RowLimit = 6;//if you want to limit number of items returned. Comment if not required.
>         myquery.Query = "Your Caml query here";
>
>         SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(myquery);
>
>         foreach (SPListItem item in items)
>         {
>             // check the item for null
>             if (item != null)
>             {
>                 // do something
>             }
>         }
>     }
> } }
> ```

Comment: +1 This is a really well documented answer! I am really digging that CAML Query Helper tool.